# Sending Colored Text Messages in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am working on iPhone App similar to Pimp My text available here:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pimp-my-text-send-color-text/id489972714?mt=8

I am trying to find a way for sending Colored and animated Messages as the app does.
I have tried this by using UIWebview but it seems the paste board is used in the app to send the iMessage but its not working. The paste board copies the message from editor screen of message and paste it to default iMessage controller. But I am not sure how it is done in the app.

Can anyone suggest any way to send the Colored, animated text with effects?

Comment: The app you're referring to is actually creating pictures, and those pictures are sent as mms (or iMessage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by following code:

```
 UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
           pasteboard.persistent = YES;
           NSString *imagefile =app.strimagepath;

           ///  
           BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagefile];

           if (fileExists)
           {    
               NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagefile]);
               pasteboard.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
           }
           NSString *phoneToCall = @"sms: 123-456-7890";
           NSString *phoneToCallEncoded = [phoneToCall stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
           NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneToCallEncoded];

           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Here app.strimgPath is the path of image stored in document directory. when the MessageView is opened. Longpress and click on Paste and message will be pasted.

May be the question I asked did not clarified correctly as what I want. But the above was something that solved my purpose.